# Is it possible to override receiver behavior?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a class like this:

```
class User
  def initialize(name, id)
     @name = name
     @id = id
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def id
    @id
  end
end
```

In this case, if I initialize a user with `u = User.new("Joe", 5)`, calling `u.name` will return `"Joe"`. But if I call an unknown method, for example `User.location`, I will get a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Is there a way to override the receiver behavior or the `User` class, such that when I call `User.location`, it would simply return a `nil` value?

I've tried to monkeypatch the `send` method, but that method only works when calling `User.send :location`.

Comment: `def method_missing(method_name,*args);end` will do it. Now any method that does not exist will return `nil` (**I am in no way endorsing this**)

Comment: @engineersmnky just discovered that on a wiki page like 5 seconds after you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

It seems like the answer would involve overriding the `method_missing` method of a class. As one of the commenters said, you could do

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  nil
end
```

More on this here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Special_methods.

Comment: No that is not what I said at all. What you have posted is a stack level error if I have ever seen one. `method_missing` will essential catch a `NoMethodError` and try and handle it but you are handling it by calling the same method again which is now just a vicious circle until the program crashes.

Comment: I realized my mistake, I don't know why irb didn't catch that while I was editing this post. Will edit it this.